# Formatting Floating point number in java upto 3 precison of decimal

Tags: java, floating-point-precision

I have a variable type float.I  wanted to print it upto 3 precision of decimal including trailing zeros.

Example :

2.5 >> 2.500

1.2 >> 1.200

1.3782 >> 1.378

2 >> 2.000

I am trying  it by using

```
DecimalFormat _numberFormat= new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
Float.parseFloat(_numberFormat.format(2.5))
```

But it is not converting 2.5 >> 2.500.

Am I doing something wrong..

Please help..

Comment: Why are you calling `Float.parseFloat` on the output?

Comment: The output of _numberFormat.format(2.5) is string and I need to set this new formatted value in another float variable before printing it..that's why I am calling Float.parseFloat...

Comment: A `float` is just a number. It doesn't have any information about how many digits you want to use when you display it. Only the string representation has that information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is mistake `Float.parseFloat` this is converting back to 2.5

Output of  `_numberFormat.format(2.5)` is `2.500`

But this `Float.parseFloat` makes it back to 2.5

So your code **must be**

```
DecimalFormat _numberFormat= new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
_numberFormat.format(2.5)
```

Comment: Only just spotted that +1 to you for the eagle eye

Answer (score 3):

Try formatting as below :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.applyPattern(".000");
System.out.println(df.format(f));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
System.out.printf("%.3f", 2.5);
```

The printf-Method allows you to specify a format for your input. In this case `%.3f` means

> Print the following number as a floating point number with 3 decimals

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a decimal to a formatted string then parsing it into a float.

Floats don't care if they read 2.500 or 2.5, although the former is formatted.

The float is not going to hold trailing zeroes as IEEE754 cannot handle specifying the number of significant fihgures.

Comment: @MadProgrammer <strike>Fixed</strike>Rewritten, my bad.